# Mysql Get Result by 1 day interval period

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am not so good at database query. I need some help.

I have a database table `tbl_orders`. In this table ordered date time is stored as per GMT.

Now I want to show an analytics in which user will select a date range in IST. That I will get in the post.

e.g. user has selected 01/04/2016 to 30/04/2016

Now I want to show total order amount of each date.

But in database date time stored in GMT so I need to first convert **IST date to GMT datetime** and then I need to execute an sql query for each date.

That means if there are 30 days then 30 SQL queries will be executed.

The first query will be executed like

```
SELECT SUM(order_amount) FROM tbl_order WHERE order_date=<'2016-03-31 18:30:00'  
AND orer_date>'2016-04-01 18:30:00'
```

The second query will be executed like

```
SELECT SUM(order_amount) FROM tbl_order WHERE order_date=<'2016-04-01
18:30:00' AND orer_date>'2016-04-02 18:30:00'
```

And so on .....

So I want to know that is there any way by which I can get this result set by executing a single query.

Comment: *30 days then 30 sql queries* how? you can do it in single query. Add your table structure and code which you tried in question.

Comment: Because I have user input in IST date but in database datetime stored in GMT. So if IST date is 01/04/2016 then in GTM it is 31-03-2016 18:30:00 to 01-04-2016 18:30:00

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE order_date BETWEEN '2016-03-31 18:30:00' AND '2016-03-31 18:30:00'` Just put your start and end dates in the sql and loop the results, probably want to order by date_order too

Comment: Not got the idea but, after understanding your question, You can use **OR** in your sql query. so that if you are having date of that 30 days in table then you will get all the results.

Comment: @Dale I need total order amount for each date but when I do as you said then order amount of 2016-03-31 20:00:00 is not included as I am passing date as per IST. Another thing is I need one row for each date.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: @Sandeep Nope. I don't understand the question, so I can't really comment on an answer.

Comment: @Strawberry As per my understanding, (1)he want to search total `order_amount` for each day for a given time period. (2) the table contains dates which are in GMT but the user input is in IST so he also wants to convert the user input date  to GMT in mysql and execute the first condition.

Comment: @Sandeep OK. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN order_date >= '2016-03-31 18:30:00' AND order_date < '2016-04-01 18:30:00'
                THEN order_amount END),
       SUM(CASE WHEN order_date >= '2016-04-01 18:30:00' AND order_date < '2016-04-02 18:30:00'
                THEN order_amount END)
FROM tbl_order;
```

Notes.  The proper way to expression `<=` is `<=`.  Also, the order of the comparisons was not correct, so the original values would be `NULL`.

Comment: Dates can be any I mean dynamic so I can not use it as you said in SQL query. Also as per your idea I will get one column for each date. I want one row for each date

Comment: @Strawberry User select a date range in IST. In database date time stored in GMT. Now I want to calculate total order_amount for each date from date range. I am converting IST date to GMT datetime using PHP. Now I have date range in GMT. But I want result set for each date like 2016-03-31 18:30:00 to 2016-04-01 18:30:00. Next row will be for 2016-04-01 18:30:00 to 2016-04-02 18:30:00

Comment: @strawberry I hope you are getting my question now.

Comment: @HardikDesai A vain hope I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and check if the output is as per your requirement (if you have converted the dates to GMT in php):

```
SELECT order_date,SUM(order_amount) FROM tbl_order WHERE order_date between   
'2016-03-31 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-30 00:00:00' GROUP BY order_date DESC;
```

**Note:** the first date should be always less than the second date.

---

IST is 5.30 hours ahead of GMT, so for converting IST time to GMT you have to subtract  5.30 hours from IST time, this can be done using the below query (if you plan to convert the date from IST to GMT in MYSQL query)

```
SELECT order_date,SUM(order_amount) FROM tbl_order WHERE order_date between   
convert_tz('2016-03-31 00:00:00','+00:00','-05:30') AND
convert_tz('2016-04-30 00:00:00','+00:00','-05:30') GROUP BY order_date DESC;
```

Comment: But I am not getting that how to get one row for each date range. e.g. For 2016-03-31 18:30:00 to 2016-04-01 18:30:00 one row. For 2016-04-01 18:30:00 to 2016-04-02 18:30:00 another row. As per my knowledge GROUP BY does not provide me this result.

Comment: If I am selecting a range of 30 days then I need to execute 30 queries as per your idea. I want the result in single query.

Comment: @HardikDesai  you have to replace dates according to your range i did for on day, see updated answer.

Comment: @HardikDesai And this query calculates `sum(order_amount)` for every day i,e from 00:00 hrs to 23:59 hrs, if you want between 18:30 hrs to 18:30 hrs its not possible using this.